# Make contents of a div into a movable resizable button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a button that basically will go on top of a leaflet map. It uses animate.css and wow.js to animate certain things and it works ok. It is made up of a div, an image, text and a span. What I need to do is make the whole thing into a div or something that I can resize and move without changing all the CSS etc. If I want to add an extra 2 or 3 buttons it will be a lot of hassle. I need to be able to move and resize depending on the screen resolution. I want to be able to use media queries to change just one thing like the size and position of the div but maintain the functionality.

I have tried putting everything into a new div but no joy!

I have included a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eLron3d2/1/

The HTML is :

```
<div id="start_box" class ="animated bounceIn">
<img id="target" class="targetimg" src="https://www.faces2places.co.uk/img/target.png" onclick="golive()"></img><button id="startbutton" type="button" class="btn-target animated bounceInLeft"></button>
<span id="status" class="btn-target-name animated fadeIn delaydn">START</span>
</div>
```

The CSS is :

```
#start_box {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    /* right: 20px; */
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
    border: 2px solid;
    border: radius:20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: #969696;
}

.targetimg {
position:relative;
    top: 4px;
    left: 8px;
 border-radius: 2.5px;
display:flex;
width:60px;
height:60px;

  animation-duration: 30000ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear; 
}

.btn-target {
background-color: white !important;
    position: fixed;
    width: 72px;
    height: 16px;
    top: 67.5px;
    left: 2.2px;
    color: #000000;
    border: 2px solid #969696;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px
}

.btn-target-name {
color:green;
font-family: 'Passion One', cursive;
display: block;
width: 76px;
    top: 70.5px;
    font-size: 12px;
font-weight:0;
text-align: center;
position: fixed;
}

.delaydn {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

.goliveactive {
  animation-duration: 30000ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-name: spin;
}


@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);

    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);

    }
}
```

And the JS is

```
window.live = false;
window.directions = true;


function golive() {


if (window.live === false) {
  $("#target").addClass("goliveactive"); 
    $('#status').css('color', '#ff3258');
    $('#status').text('FINISH');
    window.live = true;
    } else if (window.live = true) {
    $("#target").removeClass("goliveactive ");
    $('#status').css('color', 'green');
    $('#status').text('START');
    window.live = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what you want exactly, the code you tried that is not working? Thanks

Comment: The jsfiddle is an example of what I want the button to look and act like. The code is  above and on there! Not sure what else I can add?

Comment: It works fine for me, I tried to put everything in another `div` and it still works, that's why I am not too sure what's the problem exactly.

Comment: ok, try and place into another div and then move the new button to the bottom left of the page, it will be all wrong, mainly because of the fixed positioning which is easily changed ut it still isnt right

Comment: oh and also resize the new button will not work either

Comment: That's why I think you should post an example of what you are trying to do, it will be easier to help you if we can see the code that is not working. I am not sure if I am reproducing your bug correctly right now. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186970/discussion-between-armel-and-larry-chambers).

Comment: Yes we will, I am just trying a different method first, appreciate your help and will be in touch shortly

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have done it like so

http://jsfiddle.net/eLron3d2/2/

I wrapped everything into a button and changed pretty much everything to % not fixed sizes. I can change the size and position of it in the .target css

It works pretty good apart from I would like to change the font size to automatically change to fit but that one thing is easy to do with media queries, at least I don't have to change everything. The only thing is, the font does'nt load and show properly in jsfiddle but works on all browsers I have checked it with.

The HTML for 2 buttons is

```
<button class="btn target animated fadeIn"><span id="btn1" class="btnimage animated rubberBand" onclick="golive()"></span><span class="btn1textbox animated bounceInLeft"></span><span id="status" class="btn1text animated delaydn fadeIn">START</span></button>
<button class="btn target animated fadeIn delaybox"><img class="driverimg animated fadeIn" src="http://www.faces2places.co.uk/img/jules.jpg" onclick="alert('FUCKME')"></img><span class="btn1textbox animated bounceInLeft delaybox"></span><span id="status" class="btn1text animated delaydn2 fadeIn">JUSTIN.C</span></button>
```

The CSS is

```
.btn {
position: relative;
display: block;
margin-bottom:12px;
 color: white;
 font-size: 16px;
 cursor: pointer;
 border: 2px solid;
    padding: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
width:80px;
height:80px;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: #969696;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px
}

.target {
left:100px;
width:80px;
height:80px;
top:100px;
}

.btn1textbox {
position: absolute;

left: 5%;
top: 92%;
display: inline-block;
 color: white;
 border: 2px solid;
   width: 86.5%;
    height: 16%;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: #969696;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px
}

/* Darker background on mouse-over */
.btn:hover {

}

@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);

    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);

    }
}

.btnimage {
position: relative;
background:url(https://www.faces2places.co.uk/img/target.png) no-repeat center;
display: inline-block;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-size: 80% 80%;
top:-4px;

}

.btndriver {
position: relative;

display: inline-block;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-size: 80% 80%;


}

.btn1text {
font-family: 'Passion One', cursive;
color:green;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top: -12px;
 font-size: 13px;

}

.goliveactive {
  animation-duration: 30000ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-name: spin;
}

.delaydn {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-delay: .8s;
}

.delaybox {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-delay: .5s;
}

.delaydn2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-delay: 1.3s;
}

button:focus {outline:0;}

.driverimg {
position:relative;
top:-1;
 border-radius: 2.5px;
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

and the JS is

```
new WOW().init();
window.live = false;
window.directions = true;

function golive() {

if (window.live === false) {
    $("#btn1").addClass("goliveactive"); 
    $('#status').css('color', '#ff3258');
    $('#status').text('FINISH');
    window.live = true;
    } else if (window.live = true) {
    $("#btn1").removeClass("goliveactive ");
    $('#status').css('color', 'green');
    $('#status').text('START');
    window.live = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `onclick="alert('FUCKME')"`...